# Back Bar Button Segue hides Toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar, backbarbuttonitem

I am using a `Show` segue in my application.
Whenever I segue to another screen and press the back bar button, my `navigationController.toolbar` disappears.

I tried to get rid of it with

```
        navigationController?.toolbar.hidden = false
```

in my `viewDidLoad()`.
It doesn't work though. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting it in `viewWillAppear()`?

Comment: You wanna hide the navigationBar when pressing the back button, or the navigationBar is disappearing and you want it to not disappear?

Comment: @DiogoAntunes I want it to appear, rather than hide. It hides automatically.

Comment: @ViktorSimkó This is it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the code in the viewWillAppear() and it should solve the problem you are facing.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
```

}

Remember that viewDidLoad() fires only once during the life cycle of a view controller and in your case , it is in the navigation stack which means it has been already used for that view controller and now when you press back button, it does not work again.

Comment: Thanks. Also for the brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false`

Comment: Thank you. It is important to put it in ViewWillAppear()